# With the new security problem of nginx on 14.04, how do I tell what version I have?

Tags: 14.04, nginx

I just saw a report on Facebook about 14.04 having a security issue related to nginx. I followed the link and update instructions, but how do I find out which version I have on my machine to see if it worked?

Comment: `apt-cache policy nginx`. (Since I don't know anything about this vulnerability, and the USN has nothing now, I'm not posting an answer. Others, please, feel free to do so.)

Comment: Checking, is this what you're talking about? http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2351-1/

Comment: I think so but the Facebook post took me to [here](http://www.tuxoid.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-developers-find-security-issue-nginx-learn-fix/)

Comment: Comparing version numbers, that looks like the same thing. Irresponsible of them to not mention the CVE or the USN notice, but something's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only recent (past 10 days) vulnerability of `nginx` I can find on the Ubuntu security notices is [CVE-2014-3616](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2351-1/). Version `1.4.6-1ubuntu3.1` contains the fix for that CVE. Check with:

```
$ apt-cache policy nginx-core
nginx-core:
  Installed: 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.1
  Candidate: 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.1
```

(All the `nginx` packages should be upgraded together, but you can check the status of each package individually as well.)